# Flickr javascript framework

Tags: javascript, flickr

I am looking at 3rd party frameworks [list](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) for Flickr. There are frameworks for a lot of languages but surprisingly not for Javascript.

Is there any Javascript framework for Flickr?

Comment: you cannot do flicker OAuth Api using js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This github project](https://github.com/othermedia/flickr) is a JavaScript wrapper library for the Flickr API. It's written by [othermedia](https://github.com/othermedia).